# Docker image for windows with oracle12

Tags: oracle, docker, docker-image

I got my Docker up and running on windows,

Now I am looking for an oracle container for my application that needs an oracle database.

Is there an image of oracle 12 that I can use in **windows docker**?

I looked in **dockerhub** but I only found images that are built for Linux docker.

Comment: did you find a solution for your problem ?

Comment: sadly no....But I stopped looking for a solution few months ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oracle is not planning to submit such an image. They hide behind legal terms that disallow them to distribute windows binaries, see
https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/issues/208

So unless somebody from community creates one, there is none.